# Combine table with data with other .csv template by preserving the order of the column in the template

Tags: r

I have a table with data named `dat`, as below:

```
               Alison.Wong Bruno.Dumon Edward.J..Yoon Eugene.Koontz Jakob.Homan
Alison Wong              0           0              0             1           1
Bruno Dumon              0           0              0             0           1
Edward J. Yoon           0           1              0             0           0
Eugene Koontz            0           0              0             0           1
Jakob Homan              1           0              1             0           0
```

dput(head(dat)

```
structure(list(Alison.Wong = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Bruno.Dumon = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Edward.J..Yoon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Eugene.Koontz = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Jakob.Homan = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Alison.Wong", 
"Bruno.Dumon", "Edward.J..Yoon", "Eugene.Koontz", "Jakob.Homan"
), row.names = c("Alison Wong", "Bruno Dumon", "Edward J. Yoon", 
"Eugene Koontz", "Jakob Homan"), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I combine the table above (which contains data) with other .csv template by preserving the order of the column in the template and also by preserving the data from the input file (`dat`), and save it with other name.

sample template file:

```
                Adrian.Cole Alison.Wong Andrei.Savu Bruno.Dumon Edward.J..Yoon
Adrian Cole               0           0           0           0              0
Alison Wong               0           0           0           0              0
Andrei Savu               0           0           0           0              0
Bruno Dumon               0           0           0           0              0
Edward J. Yoon            0           0           0           0              0
Eugene Koontz             0           0           0           0              0
Jakob Homan               0           0           0           0              0
Kelvin Kakugawa           0           0           0           0              0
                Eugene.Koontz Jakob.Homan Kelvin.Kakugawa
Adrian Cole                 0           0               0
Alison Wong                 0           0               0
Andrei Savu                 0           0               0
Bruno Dumon                 0           0               0
Edward J. Yoon              0           0               0
Eugene Koontz               0           0               0
Jakob Homan                 0           0               0
Kelvin Kakugawa             0           0               0
```

dput(head(template)):

```
structure(list(Adrian.Cole = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Alison.Wong = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Andrei.Savu = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Bruno.Dumon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Edward.J..Yoon = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Eugene.Koontz = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Jakob.Homan = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Kelvin.Kakugawa = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Adrian.Cole", "Alison.Wong", 
"Andrei.Savu", "Bruno.Dumon", "Edward.J..Yoon", "Eugene.Koontz", 
"Jakob.Homan", "Kelvin.Kakugawa"), row.names = c("Adrian Cole", 
"Alison Wong", "Andrei Savu", "Bruno Dumon", "Edward J. Yoon", 
"Eugene Koontz"), class = "data.frame")
```

sample output from this example:

```
                Adrian.Cole Alison.Wong Andrei.Savu Bruno.Dumon Edward.J..Yoon
Adrian Cole               0           0           0           0              0
Alison Wong               0           0           0           0              0
Andrei Savu               0           0           0           0              0
Bruno Dumon               0           0           0           0              0
Edward J. Yoon            0           0           0           1              0
Eugene Koontz             0           0           0           0              0
Jakob Homan               0           1           0           0              1
Kelvin Kakugawa           0           0           0           0              0
                Eugene.Koontz Jakob.Homan Kelvin.Kakugawa
Adrian Cole                 0           0               0
Alison Wong                 1           1               0
Andrei Savu                 0           0               0
Bruno Dumon                 0           1               0
Edward J. Yoon              0           0               0
Eugene Koontz               0           1               0
Jakob Homan                 0           0               0
Kelvin Kakugawa             0           0               0
```

I tried to use the following script, but it doesnt work.

```
template<- read.table("CR_template.csv", header=T, sep=",", row.names=1)
    template[match(rownames(cr), rownames(template)) , names(cr)] <- cr[ , names(cr)]
    result <- merge(cr, template)
    write.csv(result, paste("CR_FILES_", a.files[i], sep=""))
```

Comment: it would be immensely useful if you could show what you tried.

Comment: @RJ-I insert the script that I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example you offered, it is incredibly easy:

```
template[ , names(dat)] <- dat[ , names(dat)]
```

However, what you posted as data does not match up with the (square) dimensions you are reporting for both 'dat' and 'template'. So I would suggest you post a much smaller example for `dat`, say 5 x 5, and a slightly bigger example for 'template', say 8 x 8, and also  post what you think the right answer should be.

If there needs to be interleaving of both columns and rows then it's possble something along these lines will succeed, but at the moment I consider it untested:

```
template[match(rownames(dat), rownames(template)) , names(dat)] <- dat[ , names(dat)]
```

For the edited version, this works:

```
datrows <- match(rownames(template), rownames(dat) )
transfer <- dat[ datrows[!is.na(datrows)], ]
template[rownames(transfer) , colnames(transfer) ] <- transfer

> template
               Adrian.Cole Alison.Wong Andrei.Savu Bruno.Dumon Edward.J..Yoon Eugene.Koontz Jakob.Homan
Adrian Cole              0           0           0           0              0             0           0
Alison Wong              0           0           0           0              0             1           1
Andrei Savu              0           0           0           0              0             0           0
Bruno Dumon              0           0           0           0              0             0           1
Edward J. Yoon           0           0           0           1              0             0           0
Eugene Koontz            0           0           0           0              0             0           1
               Kelvin.Kakugawa
Adrian Cole                  0
Alison Wong                  0
Andrei Savu                  0
Bruno Dumon                  0
Edward J. Yoon               0
Eugene Koontz                0
```

Comment: i tried the script above, and also tried template[ , names(dat) ] <- dat, but it doesnot copy the data in the `dat`

Comment: I have edited the question. I also include the sample output for the question.

Comment: I don't understand "getting banned". There are 2 close close votes but that was before you provided a complete example and it takes 4 votes to close. I doubt the question will get closed now that there is an answer.

Comment: I see no evidence of any "ban". What are you talking about?

Comment: @DWin, when users post/repost lots of poor questions they are temporarily [banned from asking questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998)

Comment: Oh, well I must not have been seeing the other questions. This question surely did _not_ deserve a ban. He included an example and fixed the problems reasonably promptly when it was pointed out.

Comment: @GSee, As a novice programmer, I tried to make an adjustment to the question. I can say, there are a lot of questions which sometimes do not comply with the guideline. But, do they got banned? Novice/beginner programmer with very weak english proficiency like me has a lot of things to learn, and of course we sometimes have a difficulty to express the questions. Maybe, we should have a 'proof-reader' filtering here?

Comment: @user1676484, I had nothing to do with your ban.  It is determined by an algorithm as outlined in the link I shared.